# The CEO wants to kitesurf with me

Tags: socializing, social-nuances

The CEO wants to kitesurf with me during working time.

I have no trouble with that. But I'm trying to figure out the reasons behind this activity.

```
Why does a CEO wants to do something like that?
```

What's the point of it? No money is made while we were kitesurfing during working time.

Comment: There doesn't have to be an ulterior motive.  If you want to go kitesurfing, go kitesurfing.

Comment: Because they want to get to know you better? Because they like or want to try kite surfing? Because they want someone to go kite surfing with? Why do you think there's anything else going on here? Just because they're a CEO doesn't mean absolutely everything they do is about money - they're still human.

Comment: There is more to the bottom line than the bottom line.  Good relationships and taking care of your people are great for business.

Comment: *Probably* this means the CEO wants to build/strengthen their relationship with you. *Probably* the professional relationship, though they could also be seeking a personal relationship, which is a possibility you should at least be aware of.

Comment: If you do go, just assume that your CEO/Company probably won't be responsible for any injury you may suffer...

Comment: Do you enjoy kite surfing? Did you express an interest in kite surfing to him?  If so I would suspect that is why he asked you to go.  Why during working time? Because that is the best time to do it.  Why do it with you?  Because you are a member of his team and he wants to build a relationship with you... and he probably loves to go kite surfing and can write it off as a business expense.

Comment: Maybe he wants to be more like Richard Branson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't something we can truly answer; we're not your CEO (unless, perhaps one of us actually is!), so we don't know their intentions.

However, if you want to go kitesurfing, go kitesurfing. There likely isn't any malicious background to doing this, and besides that, having a good relationship with the CEO is something to be proud of. Keep that relationship, and it could definitely come in handy in the future.

Comment: I think OPs concern is more about it being on the clock, not just getting a request to kite-surf in general as a social interaction!

Comment: Question is on hold so there isn't much reason to edit, but regardless, i think my answer applies; the CEO doesn't seem to consider it a detraction of working time, so it's an opportunity to experience.